# How to map objects to enums in Swift without throwing an exception

Tags: design-patterns, swift

I have some array that I need to map to an array of enums:

```
let planets = ["Earth", "Mars", "Venus"]

enum Planet {
  case Earth
  case Mars
  case Venus
}
```

The array is vetted (f.e. I do a filter on it before conversion)

Now, in my mapping function

```
func stringToPlanet(planetStr: String) -> Planet {
  switch planetStr {
  ...
    default:
      return ???
  }
}
```

I have to return something in the default section, so I have the following options:

- Add an "Unknown" planet to enum (but I know 100% that all planets in my enum are known)
- Return Planet? and .None in default (cleanest, but down the line I need non-optional enums to I would have to filter with unwrapping. What about wrapping/unwrapping performance? I have a tight loop that calls this function.)
- Return .Earth (satisfactory result outside the function, but eew)

If this would be another language, I would just throw here knowing that it would never happen. What's your opinion on the best pattern here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fromRaw` function

```
enum Planet : String {
    case Earth = "Earth";
    case Mars = "Mars";
    case Venus = "Venus";
}


var f = Planet.fromRaw("Earth")

f == Planet.Earth  // true
```

If the plant name is invalid, `f` will be set to nil

More info in apple doc here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_228

Comment: It should also be noted that you do not explicitly need to set the `enum`'s `String` values.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make compiler happy is to assert failure:

```
func stringToPlanet(planetStr: String) -> Planet {
  switch planetStr {
  ...
  default:
    assertionFailure("Wow, new planet")
  }
}
```

This way you don't have to pollute your nice enum with raw values ;)